# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.dlopen(Ljava/lang/String;)J

Tags: raspberry-pi, shared-libraries, jnetpcap

I am working with a Raspberry pi 3 b+. My program is in java and I am using the jnetpcap library. When executing the code, I get the following error:

[image: error jnetpcap]

I think the problem is that the shared object (.so) corresponding to jnetpcap is not the one for arm architecture (but in Linux). How could I get or convert the current that I have to be working in arm architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible solution for the RPi 3 b+ is to compile de source code of the jnetpcap project because there is no precompiled version getting directly the *.so (arm architecture 32 bits). The problem is that the last version of the project is from 2013 so the dependencies get really hard to obtain because of the versions.
I decided to implement the function that I wanted (open pcaps and process them) in the RPi (jnetpcap available for Ubuntu) with another library called pcap4j and it worked fine.